# AsyncTask stops after some time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a CustomAsyncTask class that enables infinite barcode scanner and I execute it in CustomApplication.
Unfortunately `CustomAsyncTask::doInBackground` stops after some time (minute or two).

```
private class ScanAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>
{
    boolean blocked = false;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (!blocked)
            {
                String received = GlobalAccess.scan.scan(500);

                if (received != null && !received.isEmpty())
                {
                    blocked = true;
                    publishProgress(received);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //TODO: something with received value
        blocked = false;
    }
}
```

I need this background task to be always on. Is there any good solution for this? I have tried IntentService, but the result was the same - after some time it stopped working.

---

**EDIT**

I have created this Service, although it block my main thread, but it should work in background right? Also If I put a breakpoint on `if(!blocked)` and press F9 it works fine (scanning part), but if I remove breakpoint and let it run - after few seconds it just turns off (scanner), but if I put a breakpoint again - it works again (sic!).

```
public class ScanService extends Service
{
    boolean blocked = false;

    public ScanService()
    {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (!blocked)
            {
                String received = GlobalAccess.scan.scan(500);

                if (received != null && !received.isEmpty())
                {
                    //blocked = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace. `AsyncTask` should be used for a couple seconds at most. If you need something to run indefinitely then use a service and with a thread. If it's still crashing then there's a problem within your code.

Comment: I recommend you to use JobDispatcher for these jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) instead of AsyncTask. AsyncTasks are only designed to run with shorter background tasks. Keep in mind that whatever you run in a `Service` will execute on the main thread, so you should use a background thread within your `Service`.

Can you tell why the AsyncTask or IntentService is stopping? With an `IntentService`, with your while(true) loop, it should run indefinitely unless the app gets shut down for some reason.

Edit -

You need to do this to prevent your loop from blocking the main thread -

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
          public void run() {
                 while(true) {
                 // your code here
           }
      }
   });
   t.start();
}
```

I don't know why your Service is stopping. You need to be looking at your Logcat output. Set the filter to Error and you're crash should show up there.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Could you tell me how can I check why IntentService stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an elegant solution for this type of thing. Use a service. In particular, the JobScheduler api is meant to handle this kind of stuff. Reason for using this is, as you stated, you have a long running task and you don't want to have to manage it dying. In addition, the JobScheduler is built to handle side effects of the OS. I assume that you want your job to run, but allow the app to perform its normal set of operations. Though, as a note, the API is smart in considering factors, such as battery levels, OS resources being used, wifi connectivity, so the jobs can be deferred.

The official documentation is here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

An example of how to use it can be found here
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-jobscheduler-api-on-android-lollipop--cms-23562